Open access Springer books
Googling about Quaternions I found that the book 'Quaternion Algebras' of Professor J. Voight is Open Access (legally in Springer link). What other Springer mathematical books can one find in Open Access (undergraduate and graduate level)? Thanks a lot.

You can browse their catalog: https://link.springer.com/search?facet-content-type=%22Book%22&just-selected-from-overlay=facet-discipline&package=openaccess&facet-discipline=%22Mathematics%22&just-selected-from-overlay-value=%22Mathematics%22

@RobertIsrael Thanks a lot for the comment. Do you know other publishers (elsevier, crc, etc) that have a similar open access policy for some of their books?
